# Trying to get the correct regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am stuck trying to make the right range of numbers correlate to each of the three letters!
This is what I have so far: `\w*[EWO]-\d{1,2}`

The question is as follows:
Personnel employed by the United States government are assigned a pay grade that determines their annual salary. The pay grade is a code that begins with the letter E, W, or O (each of which is uppercase). The first letter is followed by a single dash and then exactly one or two digits. Valid E pay grades move from 1 up through 9. Valid W pay grades move from 1 up through 5. Valid O pay grades move from 1 up through 10. Some valid pay grade classifications include E-1, W-5, O-1, and O-10. Examples of invalid pay grade classifications would be E-10, W-6, and O-20.

Comment: Trying to capture all at once using regex is a bad idea... Split into the 3 different cases (E/W/O) and then check each one separately, it will also make your code much clearer and way less convoluted.

Comment: but how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

If the letter is an O, O-10 is valid. Regex: `O-10`

If the letter is an O, O-1 through O-9 is valid. Regex: `O-[1-9]`

If the letter is an E, E-1 through E-9 is valid. Regex: `E-[1-9]`

If the letter is an W, W-1 through W-5 are valid. Regex: `W-[1-5]`

Put them all together using alternation: `O-10|O-[1-9]|E-[1-9]|W-[1-5]`

The only trick is to make sure the longest match is first. You have to put `O-10` first because otherwise O-10 would be matched by `O-[1-9]` and it wouldn't match the zero.

Finally, since `O-[1-9]` and `E-[1-9]` are both valid, we can combine them, giving: `O-10|[EO]-[1-9]|W-[1-5]`